# How to correctly solve 1D wave equation to get displacement profile (periodic Boundary Condition problem)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, discretization

I'm trying to solve a 1D wave equation for the pile with periodic BC (periodic load).

I'm pretty sure about my discretization formulas. The only thing I'm not sure about is the periodic BC and time (*t*) in there ==> `sin(omega*t)`.

When I set it up as it is right now, it's giving me a weird displacement profile. However, if I set it up to be `sin(omega*1)` or `sin(omega*2)`,... etc, it resembles a sine wave, but it basically means that `sin(omega*t)`, i.e. `sin(2*pi*f*t)`, is equal to 0 when *t* is an integer value..

I code everything up in Jupyter Notebook together with the visualization part, but the solution is nowhere near the propagating sine wave.

Here is the relevant Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def oned_wave(L, dz, T, p0, Ep, ro, f):

    """Solve u_tt=c^2*u_xx on (0,L)x(0,T]"""
    """Assume C = 1"""

    p = p0
    E = Ep
    ro = ro
    omega = 2*np.pi*f
    c = np.sqrt(E/ro)
    C = 1                                     # Courant number

    Nz = int(round(L/dz))
    z = np.linspace(0, L, Nz+1)               # Mesh points in space
    dt = dz/c                                 # Time step based on Courant Number
    Nt = int(round(T/dt))
    t = np.linspace(0, Nt*dt, Nt+1)           # Mesh points in time
    C2 = C**2                                 # Help variable in the scheme

    # Make sure dz and dt are compatible with z and t
    dz = z[1] - z[0]
    dt = t[1] - t[0]

    w = np.zeros(Nz+1)                        # Solution array at new time level
    w_n = np.zeros(Nz+1)                      # Solution at 1 time level back
    w_nm1 = np.zeros(Nz+1)                    # Solution at 2 time levels back

    # Set initial condition into w_n
    for i in range(0,Nz+1):
        w_n[i] = 0

    result_matrix = w_n[:]                    # Solution matrix where each row is displacement at given time step

    # Special formula for first time step
    for i in range(1, Nz):
        w[i] = 0.5*C2 * w_n[i-1] + (1 - C2) * w_n[i] + 0.5*C2 * w_n[i+1]

    # Set BC
    w[0] = (1 - C2) * w_n[i] + C2 * w_n[i+1] - C2*dz*((p*np.sin(omega*dt))/E) # this is where, I think, the mistake is: sin(omega*t)
    w[Nz] = 0

    result_matrix = np.vstack((result_matrix, w)) # Append a row to the solution matrix

    w_nm1[:] = w_n; w_n[:] = w                # Switch variables before next step

    for n in range(1, Nt):
        # Update all inner points at time t[n+1]
        for i in range(1, Nz):
            w[i] = - w_nm1[i] + C2 * w_n[i-1] + 2*(1 - C2) * w_n[i] + C2 * w_n[i+1]

        # Set BC
        w[0] = - w_nm1[i] + 2*(1 - C2) * w_n[i] + 2*C2 * w_n[i+1] - 2*dz*((p*np.sin(omega*(dt*n)))/E) # this is where, I think, the mistake is: sin(omega*t)
        w[Nz] = 0

        result_matrix = np.vstack((result_matrix, w)) # Append a row to the solution matrix

        w_nm1[:] = w_n; w_n[:] = w            # Switch variables before next step

    return result_matrix
```

[My Jupyter Notebook document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dOtcB_nbvkvC0_1YdqAJN8tDDsCqRMmq).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Best practice is to include the relevant code in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have extracted the relevant Python code from your document, and embedded it inside the question. As commented above, it is important that the question is self-contained: make sure the problem description is complete without requiring readers to follow hyperlinks.

Comment: Which values of `f` are you testing with? If that's an integer then `sin(2*pi*f*t)` will return 0 for any integer `t`.

Comment: trincot, thank you for doing that.

Comment: I'm testing it with f = 5, 15, 30, etc. so it's gonna be 0 each time when I do that. However, from what I understand, time (t) should be included as dt (time step) which is rather small number ==> e.g. for dz = 0.25, dt = 0.0001 in this case, so it'll produce non-zero value. The question I keep asking myself is this correct way of thinking and if so, what I am doing wrong with the code (or discretization) that final displacement is not sine-wave-looking one